# Why has "1<ScRiPt >prompt(912" appeared in my MySQL database? Am I being hacked?

Tags: php, mysql

This has recently appeared in some of the rows in my database:

```
1<ScRiPt >prompt(912

1<ScRiPt >prompt(922

1<ScRiPt >prompt(960
```

I've recently discovered that magic_quotes is off, and the mysql_real_escape_atring function is not being used. This is in the process of being updated.

I've never seen prompt appear in any DB before, so I'm wondering if anyone knows what it could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it, looks like someone is trying to inject some javascript into your database. It appears they have failed, possibly due to a quote mark being escaped and finishing your sql update.

It shouldn't be a problem with magic quotes, since they are now deprecated and you should be using mysql_real_escape_string instead: http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I appreciate it. Feeling quite lucky that it didn't work. Magic_quotes is now on! thanks again.

Comment: @drandom - note what Jonno said about magic_quotes being deprecated - it is switched off by default, its use is not recommended, and it will be removed entirely in future versions of PHP. You should be switching to use the `mysql_real_escape_string()` function if possible.